# Magic Wand Tool on a Traced Image in Ai

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, selections, background-removal, image-trace

I have brought in an image in ai and image traced it to make it a vector. Right now I'm trying to select specific color to blend the image better. The problem is I can't select anything on the image, nothing happens... what do I do?

Please Help :)

Comment: Did you try expanding the trace first?

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that your image is expanded.

[image]

Additionally you can use the select same fill or stroke option instead of the magic wand tool.

This method is more precise than the wand due to tolerances.

[image]